# How can we call a defrule inside another defrule?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rules, rule-engine, clips

I am totally new to CLIPS and I would like to know how could we call a defrule inside another defrule.
For example if one rule does a regular job like printing or swapping, and another rule wants to call it after doing pattern-matching itself; how could the second rule call the first one in its pattern-matching part?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Chain rules by asserting a fact from one rule that activates another.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defrule start
   =>
   (assert (r1)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rule-1
   (r1)
   =>)
CLIPS> (watch rules)
CLIPS> (watch activations)
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      start: *
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
FIRE    1 start: *
==> f-1     (r1)
==> Activation 0      rule-1: f-1
FIRE    2 rule-1: f-1
CLIPS>
```